# Duplicate values in excel and sum the value of duplicate value by python

Tags: python

I want to remove duplicate item in excel and sum the value of them by using python. I have some codes but they only could remove the duplicate item and they are unable to sum the value of them.
If someone knows how I could solve this problem please give me the answer.
thanks for your favor

Comment: Can you provide a working example of your code so far with inputs as well? In this way it will be easier to answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas,

- pandas.read_excel()
- DataFrame.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=False)
- DataFrame.sum(axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None, min_count=0, **kwargs)